# Microsoft Graph - Create Teams API Returns "Bind requests not supported for containment navigation property ."

Tags: python, rest, microsoft-teams

I'm new to Microsoft Teams, I'm trying to create a team using the following API

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams
```

I'm using the following snippet of Python code to create the team.

```
url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams"
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
data = {
  "template@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates('standard')",
  "displayName": "FIRST TEAM",
  "description": "FIRST TEAM",
  "members@odata.bind": [
            {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
            "roles": '[owner]',
            "userId": "3c0d3719-6c92-4646-af05-f02df80242db"
        }
  ]
}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```

I receive the following response.

`b'{\r\n  "error": {\r\n    "code": "BadRequest",\r\n    "message": "Bind requests not supported for containment navigation property.",\r\n    "innerError": {\r\n      "date": "2020-10-12T16:58:45",\r\n      "request-id": "2063aba7-43f2-4024-912c-e7402bb1d6ba",\r\n      "client-request-id": "2063aba7-43f2-4024-912c-e7402bb1d6ba"\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}`'

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong, I tried to learn more about the error message *Bind requests not supported for containment navigation property* but couldn't find anything helpful.

Can someone please help me understand what the error means and if possible what is wrong with the request itself ?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, I had to modify `data` as follows.

```
data = {
  "template@odata.bind": r"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates('standard')",
  "displayName": "FIRST TEAM",
  "description": "FIRST TEAM",
  "members": [
            {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
            "roles": ["owner"],
            "userId": "3b0d3719-6c92-4646-af05-f02df80242db"
        }
  ]
}
```

If you can't tell the key has to be `members`
This was discovered through trial and error though I'm not sure why.

Comment: In fact, it was an error when I submitted a request using postman,using those data format.

Comment: @KevinYANG, are you saying that the answer format I posted isn't working for you ? If yes, did you also try as suggested on Microsoft's official documentation ?

Comment: Yes,I just follow this format and official document.But will get the unknown error when submit this request via postman