# Can not create a team from scratch via microsoft graph api

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I follow this document and tried to create a team in the code
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp%2Chttp.
here is my code snippets:

```
var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            // Configure the MSAL client as a confidential client
            var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithTenantId(tenantId)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .Build();
 GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient =
                new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
                {

                    // Retrieve an access token for Microsoft Graph (gets a fresh token if needed).
                    var authResult = await confidentialClient
                        .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                        .ExecuteAsync();

                    // Add the access token in the Authorization header of the API request.
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
                })
                );

            // Make a Microsoft Graph API call
            var team = new Team
            {
                DisplayName = "My Sample Team",
                Description = "My Sample Team’s Description",
                AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        {"template@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')"},
        {"members@odata.bind", "[{\"@odata.type\":\"#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember\",\"roles\":[\"owner\"],\"userId\":\"57d4fc1c-f0a3-1111-b41e-22229f05911c\"}]"}
    }
            };
 GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient =
                new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
                {

                    // Retrieve an access token for Microsoft Graph (gets a fresh token if needed).
                    var authResult = await confidentialClient
                        .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                        .ExecuteAsync();

                    // Add the access token in the Authorization header of the API request.
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
                })
                );

            // Make a Microsoft Graph API call
            var team = new Team
            {
                DisplayName = "My Sample Team",
                Description = "My Sample Team’s Description",
                AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        {"template@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')"},
        {"members@odata.bind", "[{\"@odata.type\":\"#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember\",\"roles\":[\"owner\"],\"userId\":\"57d4fc1c-f0a3-4105-b41e-1ba89f05911c\"}]"}
    }
            };
```

but get this error:

```
 "message": "Bind requests not supported for containment navigation property.",\r\n
```

I'm using the latest `Microsoft.Graph` library and version is `V3.1.8`

does anyone have some ideas on this issue or the odata format error?

Comment: Can you share the detailed error log that you got (response-id, timestamp)?

Comment: @Dev, please see the log as below:Code: BadRequest
Message: Bind requests not supported for containment navigation property.
Inner error:
 AdditionalData:
 date: 2020-10-20T08:28:22
 request-id: 42a493d8-7068-40b3-b1a8-f238501b2742
 client-request-id: 42a493d8-7068-40b3-b1a8-f238501b2742
ClientRequestId: 42a493d8-7068-40b3-b1a8-f238501b2742

Comment: @Dev do you have any findings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `members@odata.bind` is still in change. It doesn't work currently.

You need to use `members` property.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams

{
  "template@odata.bind":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')",
  "displayName":"My Sample Team555",
  "description":"My Sample Team’s Description555",
  "members":[
      {
         "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
         "roles":[
            "owner"
         ],
         "userId":"9xxxxxc9-f062-48e2-8ced-22xxxxx6dfce"
      }
   ]
}
```

The corresponding C# code should be:

```
var team = new Team
            {
                DisplayName = "My Sample Team557",
                Description = "My Sample Team’s Description557",
                Members = (ITeamMembersCollectionPage)new List<ConversationMember>()
                {
                    new AadUserConversationMember
                    {
                        Roles = new List<String>()
                        {
                            "owner"
                        },
                        UserId = "9xxxxxc9-f062-48e2-8ced-22xxxxx6dfce"
                    }
                },
                AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    {"template@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')"}
                }
            };
```

Unfortunately, when I run the code, it shows:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Graph.ConversationMember]' to type 'Microsoft.Graph.ITeamMembersCollectionPage'.'
```

I cannot make it work. The workaround is to use httpClient to send the request in your code.

See a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64322274/microsoft-graph-create-teams-api-returns-bind-requests-not-supported-for-cont).

**UPDATE:**

I have figured it out.

You can try the following code:

```
        var team = new Team
        {
            DisplayName = "My Sample Team558",
            Description = "My Sample Team’s Description558",
            Members = new TeamMembersCollectionPage() {
                new AadUserConversationMember
                {
                    Roles = new List<String>()
                    {
                        "owner"
                    },
                    UserId = "9xxxxxc9-f062-48e2-8ced-22xxxxx6dfce"
                }
            },
            AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {"template@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')"}
            }
        };
```

If you prefer httpClient method, refer to this:

```
        string str = "{\"template@odata.bind\":\"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')\",\"displayName\":\"My Sample Team999\",\"description\":\"My Sample Team’s Description555\",\"members\":[{\"@odata.type\":\"#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember\",\"roles\":[\"owner\"],\"userId\":\"9xxxxxc9-f062-48e2-8ced-22xxxxx6dfce\"}]}";

        var content = new StringContent(str, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        var response = client.PostAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams", content).Result;
```

**UPDATE 2:**

If you need to call it in Postman, use this format:

```
{
  "template@odata.bind":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')",
  "displayName":"My Sample Team555",
  "description":"My Sample Team’s Description555",
  "members":[
      {
         "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
         "roles":[
            "owner"
         ],
         "userId":"9xxxxxc9-f062-48e2-8ced-22xxxxx6dfce"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Yes,I faced the same error when I ran the code.Regarding that similar question,I already tried it but met another invalid error

Comment: In fact, it was an error when I submitted a request using postman,using those data format.

Comment: @KevinYANG I have updated the Postman sample in answer. Please check.

Comment: with this update2,I got this error:{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-10-21T03:18:04",
      "request-id": "ff889535-7333-4044-b20f-d1618ea45502",
      "client-request-id": "ff889535-7333-4044-b20f-d1618ea45502"
    }
  }
}@Allen Wu

Comment: ,and the same error with it in C# code.have you tried it in your local env?or should I need some minor change in azure add application api permisions?

Comment: @KevinYANG I have tested the code and it works fine. I can hardly tell what the issue is with `UnknownError`. Can you try this method to get the `graphServiceClient `?  `ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClient); GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223390/discussion-between-allen-wu-and-kevin-yang).